# Python telegram bot (telegram.ext)

Tags: python, telegram-bot

First thing first, I'm a beginner in Python and programming.
I want to make a telegram bot for my telegram group. I found a code o Github and I want to configure it for my needs.
I have an error when I run the code: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram'.
What do I have to install? I believe it is something related to "telegram.ext" and I have no ideea how to solve this.
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwkRo.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: Have you installed the telegram module you found with `pip install telegram`?

Answer (score 0):

I am also creating a bot in telegram using python-telegram-bot,
May these steps work :

1. Install `pip install telebot`
2. Install `pip install python-telegram-bot`
3. If you are using a virtual environment, make sure it is activated
4. Now import `from telegram.ext import *`